# "servermain postfix[23607]: error: to submit mail, use the Postfix sendmail command" при отправке сообщения

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot

Устанавил Postfix на Ubuntu, при настройке его мучался, разные статьи пробовал, но в логах при отправке сообщения всегда такая ошибка:

> Oct 16 16:59:53 servermain
>   postfix[23607]: error: to submit mail,
>   use the Postfix sendmail command Oct
>   16 16:59:53 servermain postfix[23607]:
>   fatal: the postfix command is reserved
>   for the superuser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему! Ура! 
Оказалось, что настройки dovecot были старой версии, отладил конфиг с помощью dovecot -n. И отправка из консоли заработала. 
А вот в конфиге php нужно было ещё поменять
`sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/postfix -t -i`
**на** `sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`
Всем спасибо!

Comment: Ну я же говорил.

Comment: Говорил, но самое главное надо было настроить, чтобы из консоли работал!) А php я не отлаживал даже!) Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

```
fatal: the postfix command is reserved for the superuser
```

Написано, что не хватает root прав.

Comment: Я это перевёл и уже много папок 777 поставил, не помогает. Сообщение отправляю из консоли под root аккаунтом.

Comment: @iproger, тут не в правах дело (и лучше с ними не играться с почтовым сервером, постфикс - это некислая машина о большом количестве демонов, которую очень сложно объять и отдебажить), а в том, что тянется консольная команда postfix вместо sendmail. Скорее всего, надо просто покопаться в php.ini и сменить соответствующую директиву.

Comment: Да причём тут php то, объянсите? Я из консоли отправляю сообщение, до php то ещё и руки не доходили, пока что тестирую как устанавился этот postfix. Он вот ошибки выдаёт и не отправляет ничего. Ошибки пишет связанные с правами. Неужели нельзя было делать более содержательные ошибки.

Comment: @iproger

> Да причём тут php то, объясните?

...

> всегда эта ошибка при отправке сообщения из консоли/из скрипта php.

по поводу

> Неужели нельзя было делать более содержательные ошибки.

а) я уже написал, что команду postfix тянуть не надо, надо mail/sendmail;  
б) именно это в ошибке и написано.

Comment: Мм, не понял. Я из консоли командой mail отправляю сообщение. В результате та ошибка. Sendmail ранее был - но он фигово работал, 2 минуты страница грузилась и вообще все советуют postfix. Я удалил sendmail и поставил postfix и уже 2 недели пытаюсь исправить эти ошибки, но ничего совсем ничего не помогает.

Comment: > Sendmail ранее был - но он фигово работал, 2 минуты страница грузилась и вообще все советуют postfix. Я удалил sendmail

...

>  я уже написал, что **команду postfix** тянуть не надо, надо mail/sendmail

есть сервер sendmail, есть бинарник, который может быть как от сендмэила, так и от постфикса

>  Я из консоли командой mail отправляю сообщение. В результате та ошибка. 

Думаю, тут нужно подробное описание процесса установки. Можно попробовать прокрутить dpkg-reconfigure, хотя если mail обращается к постфиксу, то уже точно знает о его существовании.

Comment: Ошибка идёт от postfixа. Устанавливал я через apt-get, плюс связал с dovecot. Может, есть какая-то стопроцентная статья, хорошая по установке на ubuntu?

Comment: @iproger, проблема в том, что постфикс это реально гигантсткая махина, и здесь, судя по всему, мало кто баловался с ее настройкой, я не очень понимаю, как mail вообще вызывает postfix. Единственная идея - сервис постфикса лежит, а mail пытается его поднять, за что получает по носу за запуск от непривилегированного пользователя. Есть пакет iredmail, в который входит всё от постфикса до roundcube, я его не ставил, но вроде рабочий вполне.